# How I set a reference to a SOAP file and use this functions in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I want create a ASP.NET Application (aspx site) that connection with a database and create userconnections for the internet. I get a Soap Data (**soapapi.wsdl**). This file have all function for create a guestuser or get Informations about who apply a GuestUser and the Time.

**My Problem** is that I don't know how I can add a reference to this Soap File in C# an execute this functions :( ? I search it but I don't found a good example :/

What I need for a Namespace and how i set a reference to this wsdl file ?

tarasov

Comment: it is same as we refer the webservice using the url of the webservice. Here instead of URL we should give the local path to the wsdl file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add Service Reference

Right click on project file ->Add Service Reference. In the dialog point to this wsdl file. 
At result a proxy c# class will be generated, that allows you to call soap methods as usual code

Comment: ok I have the reference. I see all functions and Properties now. The service has 100+ functions and no describtion -.- ...but thanks for yout help ^^